# How to call a file from the route

Tags: laravel-5

I wanted to call the file from the route on Laravel. I have a PostsController and inside there was a method name index. I created a folder inside views name posts and inside that created a file named index. I tried to print the variable into the index.blade.php file which i assigned into the PostsController, but got error. Can anyone help me. 
Here is my code

Route :

```
Route::post('/posts/index', 'PostsController@index');
```

Controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $nameIndex = "Testing";

        return view('posts/index', [
            'nameIndex' => $nameIndex
        ]);
    }
}
```

view file : posts/index.blade.php

```
My name is : {{ $nameIndex }}
```

Comment: Could you add the error you've got?

Comment: hi @عارفبنالأزرق 
i found this error
  InvalidArgumentException
 View [posts] not found.

Comment: try writing return view('posts.index' ... using dot instead of slash

Comment: its working :) , Thank you @عارفبنالأزرق

Comment: glad that it helps! you may mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Laravel supports writing the view path using both dot or slash separator
but you should be aware that this change from Linux to Windows

on Windows you use backslash

```
view('posts\index');
```

but on Linux

```
view('posts/index');
```

So it's better to use dot separator to avoid issues after hosting your code (mostly linux server)

```
view('posts.index');
```